# Add a Relation foreign key in AX2012

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax, morph-x

I have to create 2 new tables:     EmployerTypeTable  and ListDocTable

```
-------------------                                  ------------------
-EmployerTypeTable-                                 -  ListDocTable    -                
------------------_1______________________________*__------------------
-                 -                                  -                -
-                 -                                  -                -
-------------------                                  ------------------
```

An object of EmployerTypeTable can have many objects of ListDocTable (one to many)

How can I implement this in `AX2012`?

Comment: Please read ["How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

[How to: Create Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa882181.aspx)

[How to: Add a Relation to a Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa556809.aspx)

> The initial steps for adding a relation are the same regardless of the relation type that you are adding. The later steps diverge based on the relation type.
>   Remember to save your changes in the AOT.

1. In the AOT, move to Data Dictionary > Tables, and then expand the table that the relation will be added to.
2. Right-click the Relations node, and then select New Relation.
3. Right-click the newly added relation, and then select Properties.
4. Set the name of the new relationship by modifying the Name property.
5. In the Table property, select the related table.
6. Use the Validate property to determine whether the relation should be used to validate data when information is entered into forms.
7. Right-click the new relation, select New, and then click one of the following:
8. Normal to specify relation fields without conditions.
9. Field fixed to specify relation fields to restrict the records in the primary table.
10. Related field fixed to specify relation fields that restrict the records in the related table.
11. ForeignKey to specify a correspondence between a foreign key field in the present table to the primary key field in another parent table.
12. Proceed to the subsection that corresponds to the relation type that you selected in the earlier step.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Like question like answer... Thanks for editing the answer, Jan.